# How do I pipe my msbuild output to a log file from rake

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

I'm using the fabulous albacore gem with rake to build a new .NET project.  My organization is still using NAnt, and there are lots of folks who expect to see a log file when the build script executes.  How do I save the msbuild task output that gets dumped to STDOUT to a log file?

Comment: how are you running your rake tasks? from a CI server? from the command line? or ?

Comment: Hi Derick - right now, I'm running from the command line, and very soon we'll have it hooked up to hudson.  We've convinced people that hudson will be fine without a physical log file from the rake execution.  And I think I've satiated the desire for log files by using the ".parameters" option on my msbuild and nunit tasks to log output.  I'm LOVING albacore!  You guys did a great job with it.

Comment: cool. yeah, i find no real need for a log file from hudson, because hudson captures all the STDOUT into it's own logs. but if you needed it from a command line, i guess you could just redirect STDOUT into a file: rake >> build.log

Comment: It's handy to save the msbuild log file, because if you have hudson scan just the file instead of your entire build output your build could possibly be significantly faster. the msbuild logfile parser is quite slow and build output (at least ours) can be very very verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  We don't really need a build log file for our CI server (hudson), but it would still be nice to have physical files to check when the build runs locally, particularly when we're doing the check-in dance and the build fails.

Fortunately, the albacore dudes were smart enough to create a ".parameters" option, which can be used with any of the command-line tool tasks to add parameters which aren't explicitly handled by that task.  So, for example, you can add a parameter to the msbuild task to specify a logfile for MSBuild.  And it goes a little something like this:

```
BUILD_REPORTS = 'BuildReports'
MSBUILD_EXE = "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe"

directory BUILD_REPORTS

CLEAN.include BUILD_REPORTS

task :default => [:build]

desc "Build the solution"
msbuild :build => BUILD_REPORTS do |msb|
    msb.properties :configuration => :Debug
    msb.path_to_command = MSBUILD_EXE
    msb.targets :Clean, :Build
    msb.solution = "./mysolution.sln"
    msb.parameters "/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build;logfile=" + log_file("build")
end

def log_file(log_file_name)
    BUILD_REPORTS + log_file_name + ".log"
end
```

Our rakefile is a little more complex than that because it has to do more stuff, but you get the idea.